# Abrupt crash in app on a recent iOS build

Tags: ios

After updating my iOS devices to some recent version, an app of mine started regularly crashing with output:

> 2018-01-30 19:18:09.931179+0100 iPuja[40116:2592196] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[MPRequestResponseController endAutomaticResponseLoading],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MediaPlayer/MobileMusicPlayer-4015.500.25/MediaPlaybackCore/Middleware/MPRequestResponseController.m:153
>   2018-01-30 19:18:09.932192+0100 iPuja[40116:2592196] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Mismatched begin/endAutomaticResonseLoading.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1852b4238 0x18447c5ec 0x1852b40a4 0x185c9003c 0x196f552b4 0x10204d194 0x10205a478 0x10204ee5c
>   0x102051b64 0x18525c660 0x18525a1b8 0x18517a498 0x18713b020
>   0x18f5c421c 0x101022bf4 0x184c19fc0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

What might it be and how to fix it or know better?

Comment: Can you show the stack symbols for the crashing thread?  (Type "bt all" at the (lldb) prompt.)

Answer (score 4):

The issue was due to the calling of endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications without having first called beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications, a situation producing a crash in iOS 11.3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS 11.3 beta by chance?  We noticed this happening with the beta OS.  Didn't see the crash with 11.2.5.

Comment: Yes, now Apple has answered: You have unbalanced calls to begin/endGeneratingNotifications. Any app linked on iOS 11.3 or later will need to balance these calls correctly. but I have non cue about how to correct the issue.

Comment: Are you, by chance, calling begin/endGeneratingNotifications within threads that's not `main`?  That was my issue.

Comment: Nope, I simply consistently called endGenetatingNotifications while I called begin in a condition. That produced a crash when the condition was not met and end was called before a previous begin.